# Getting "error: type mismatch; found : Unit required: () => Unit" on callback

Tags: scala, types, callback

I am just starting out going through a tutorial on scala and have hit a block. I have merged together a couple of examples and am getting an error, but don't know why.

```
import java.text.DateFormat._
import java.util.{Date, Locale}

object FrenchDate {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    timer(println(frenchDate))
  }

  def frenchDate():String = {
    val now = new Date
    val df = getDateInstance(LONG, Locale.FRANCE)
    df format now
  }

  def timer(callback: () => Unit) {
    while(true) {callback(); Thread sleep 1000}
  }
}
```

Brings the error

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: () => Unit
println(frenchDate)
```

while the below works

```
import java.text.DateFormat._
import java.util.{Date, Locale}

object FrenchDate {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    timer(frenchDate)
  }

  def frenchDate() {
    val now = new Date
    val df = getDateInstance(LONG, Locale.FRANCE)
    println(df format now)
  }

  def timer(callback: () => Unit) {
    while(true) {callback(); Thread sleep 1000}
  }
}
```

The only difference is that the date is printed out in `frenchDate()` in the second once whereas it is returned and printed in the callback on the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that this line:

```
timer(println(frenchDate))
```

is trying to call `println(frenchDate)` and use the return value (which is `Unit`) as the callback to pass to `timer`. You probably want:

```
timer(() => println(frenchDate))
```

or possibly

```
timer(() => { println(frenchDate) })
```

(I'm not a Scala dev, so I'm not sure of the right syntax, but I'm pretty confident about what's wrong in your current code :)

EDIT: According to comments, this should work too and may be more idiomatic:

```
timer { () => println(frenchDate) }
```

Comment: Both should work (though I'd write it as `timer { () => println(frenchDate) }` instead).

Comment: You may also declare it as def timer(callback: => Unit) = {... callback; ...}, and call with timer(println(frenchDate)) (or timer{println(frenchDate)}, whichever you like more)

Comment: In the end did it as didierd commented here.